# Operator Compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I would like a tip for this issue

Let $K : [0, 1] × [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous mapping and $E = (C^{
0}([0, 1]), ||.||_{\infty})$. Define $J : E \rightarrow E$ by

$$Jf(x) = \int_{0}^{1}
K(x, ξ)f(ξ)dξ.$$

Prove that $J$ is compact operator. Does J has an inverse?

thanks

Comment: The question "Does $J$ have an inverse" has a clear answer: In general, not: take $K = 0$. To prove the compactness of the operator, use the Arzela Ascoli theorem.

Comment: @QuantumSpace We can say more than that: $J$ never has an inverse. The compact operators form a two sided ideal in the algebra of bounded linear operators on $E$. So if we had an invertible compact operator then the identity operator would be compact, which is never true in infinite dimensional normed spaces. And yes, to prove compactness, use Arzela-Ascoli.